# Changing the legend in dwplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to show my coefficients from two of my models. I have the following code:

```
mvh.env.coef <- dwplot(list(phy.modern.model, phy.historic.model))+
            scale_y_discrete(labels=c("distance" = "Distance", "slope" = "Slope",
                        "depth" ="Depth", "layerBIOT" = "Biot", "layerComoros" = "Comoros",
                        "layerFrance" = "France", "layerContinental EEZ" = "Continental EEZ",
                        "layerMadagascar" = "Madaagscar", "layerMaldives" = "Maldives", 
                        "layerMauritius" = "Mauritius",
                        "layerSeychelles" = "Seychelles", "layerSri lanka" = "Sri lanka"))+
            theme_bw()+ 
            ggtitle("Modern and Historic Coefficients for Sperm Whale")
{mvh.env.coef} %>% add_brackets(two_brackets)
```

[image]

I cannot seem to rename the legend at all in the plot. I have tried

```
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Model", labels = c("Modern", "Historic"))
```

but nothing changes. Does any one have any clue?

Comment: OP, your legend is for the color attribute, not fill.  Try `scale_color_discrete()`.

Comment: @chemdork123 Thank you so much! I feel so stupid for not realizing this!

Comment: It's easy to get confused - happens to us all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend is showing you the dots and line from `geom_pointrange()`, which appears to be what `dwplot()` is using to represent the coefficients.  The aesthetic you want to address here is "color", not "fill", so use any of the `scale_color_*` methods to change your legend:

```
scale_color_manual()
scale_color_discrete()
...
```